# AppleScript forward error number to osascript as exit status

Tags: bash, macos, shell, applescript, osascript

I am trying to throw a specific error code inside of a applescript snippet that I am running via `osascript`.

This is my code:

```
osascript -e "if ((clipboard info) as string) does not contain \"«class PNGf»\" then" -e "error number 61" -e "end if"
```

However, I either get statuscode `1` or `0` instead of getting either `0` or `61`. Is there any way to forward the errors?

Comment: Running **osascript** by itself returns an execution error with the provided message and number - how are you getting the result?

Comment: Well, I tried getting the actual exit code returned by the osascript process. You mean there is no other way but parsing the output?

Comment: Performing `osascript -e 'error "this is an error" number 128'` results in something like `6:24: execution error: this is an error (128)` - you can print the script errors to stdout or stderr, but that is the output from the script.

Comment: I see, I thought I might be able to make it send a exit status code instead. because parsing a string doesn't quite feel like the it should be.

Answer (score 1):

The *exit status* of `osascript` is like any other command, but you will need to look at its *output* to see the specific result of the script (which is where the error number you are interested in is coming from).

`osascript` normally prints script errors to **stderr**, but another method is to use the `-s o` option to also print script errors to **stdout**, and check the exit status to determine if you need to process the output from the script as an error (or not).